# Always create a subdocument in Mongoose and save it automatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Node.js with Mongoose and I'm trying to link documents so that when one is created and saved, a reference document is always created and saved with it:

```
var ClientSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    address: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Address'
    }
});
mongoose.model('Client', ClientSchema);

var AddressSchema = new Schema({
    street: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    postcode: {
        type: String,
        default: ''         
    }
});
mongoose.model('Address', AddressSchema);
```

I know there are pre and post hooks etc but I am still struggling with the actual implementation. Any thoughts?

Comment: Fair enough. But do you really want a load of blank address details to be added just by default? Also there is only just one address here. I think you meant to use an array. If not then why not just embed it? It's one of those cases where I would say "hang the duplication as I just don't care". I think you are trying too hard to "normalize" a NoSQL database.

Comment: There is only one address yes, the example above is just for clarity. My actual case had a much larger object that is better to keep separate for decoupling purposes. I am not so fussy about normalization. I just want an automatic trigger.

Comment: Surely you don't want to keep creating a "new" object in the referenced collection with blank properties every time a new parent is added? And "much larger object"? Well no matter what you are doing you are still taking up space. And then you need an extra query to get the referenced data to boot. I could give you the "pre" hook, but please don't take offence when the phrase "machine gun in the hands of a chimp" comes to mind. It just seems wrong and dirty to me. Embedding feels right here. Even better is leave it blank until you put something in it.

Comment: Just give me the pre hook smarty-pants ;-)